# Does writing EXIF tags influence jpeg quality?

Tags: metadata, image-quality, jpeg, image-compression

If I understand well then the EXIF data is written in an extra space of the JPEG file. When I add or modify an EXIF tag does this leave the picture untouched? I searched for this and I was not able to find an answer. I do not want to 'degrade' my pictures when I add/delete/update a tag at a later time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are tags that affect how the image can be interpreted by software (think about orientation), but no, the image bits should not be touched.

Now, lore says that there are (bad) editors that open the image (decode it) to show it, and even if you just change EXIF data, they re-encode the JPEG data instead of copying over the original. In that case, you can lose quality. I am quite sure that, for example, [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is safe (as will a lot of other tools be).

**Proof**: I start with the image `blue_boniface.jpg`, and I copy the same image to `blue_boniface_bare.jpg` and `blue_boniface_comment.jpg`:

```
% cp blue_boniface.jpg blue_boniface_bare.jpg
% cp blue_boniface.jpg blue_boniface_comment.jpg
```

Now I remove all EXIF from the first, and add a `Comment` field to the second:

```
% exiftool -all= blue_boniface_bare.jpg
% exiftool -Comment='This is a new comment' blue_boniface_comment.jpg
```

And after that I convert all the three images into PNM format (which has no ancillary data and is the barest picture format I know):

```
% jpegtopnm blue_boniface_bare.jpg > one.pnm
% jpegtopnm blue_boniface.jpg > two.pnm
% jpegtopnm blue_boniface_comment.jpg > three.pnm
% ls -l *.pnm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 24307892 Sep 13 17:57 one.pnm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 24307892 Sep 13 17:57 three.pnm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romano romano 24307892 Sep 13 17:57 two.pnm
```

The three files seems the same, let's check:

```
% diff one.pnm two.pnm
% diff one.pnm three.pnm
```

(`diff` is silent if the files are the same). So the image data is exactly the same after the EXIF file manipulation. *QED*

Comment: Excellent examples!